# Enable error logging on PHP-FPM 7 with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, ubuntu-16.04, php7

This is essentially the same as these questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677493/php-fpm-doesnt-write-to-error-log

[Nginx not logging PHP errors](https://serverfault.com/questions/417102/nginx-not-logging-php-errors)

**BUT** the answers there don't seem to be working on Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP 7.

**/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf**:

```
catch_workers_output = yes
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

`/var/log/fpm-php.www.log` exists and is owned by `www-data`.

**/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini**:

```
log_errors = On
```

**Nginx Virtual Host's Server block**

```
access_log /var/log/myapp/access.log;
error_log /var/log/myapp/error.log error;
```

/var/log/myapp/access.log exists and is owned by `www-data`.

But when an error occurs, I don't get an error in any of the specified log files, and can't find it in any other place either.

I went through all of the suggestions on the other question but didn't find any answer that worked. I'm assuming something has changed since those answer were posted. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to see `ini_get('log_errors')` and `ini_get('error_log')`, maybe your app logs them to a custom location

Comment: Create a simple file to display the output of `phpinfo()`, browse this file via browser, check the paths are correct, then remove the semicolon at the end of `phpinfo();` to trigger an error.

Comment: For Nginx related errors, please check for errors in the default file location in Ubuntu 16.04 that is `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.

Answer (score 6):

The [comment above](https://serverfault.com/questions/831249/enable-error-logging-on-php-fpm-7-with-nginx#comment1061392_831249) by [the_nuts](https://serverfault.com/users/279840/the-nuts) helped solve it for me. The directory and file didn't exist.

To diagnose, I added:

```
print("\n\n<br><br>log_errors: ".ini_get('log_errors'));
print("\n\n<br><br>error_log: ".ini_get('error_log'));
```

to the top of my code (a WordPress plugin). This outputted:

```
log_errors: 1
error_log: /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/fpm.log
```

In terminal I used *ls* to learn the file and directory were missing, i.e.

```
ls /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/fpm.log
ls /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/
```

outputted

```
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/fpm.log': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d': No such file or directory
```

To fix: I changed directory to */usr/local/etc*, **created the directory, the file and then set the owner to *www-data:www-data***

```
cd /usr/local/etc
sudo mkdir php-fpm.d
cd php-fpm.d
sudo touch fpm.log
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data fpm.log
```

If the file and directory do exist, run

```
ls fpm.log -l
```

and if owner is root:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 23 19:52 fpm.log
```

run

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data fpm.log
```

to give the web server ownership and write access

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 12848 Jun 23 20:07 fpm.log
```